# How to execute one azure function from another and test locally?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have two azure function one is to process message and another is to send email.

I want to test locally first how to call one function from another and run locally?

function1 - service bus trigger

```
 [FunctionName("procesmessage")]
        public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("demo", "demo", AccessRights.Manage, Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")]string mySbMsg, TraceWriter log)
        {
        // how to call another azure function here locally?
```

function2 - http trigger

```
[FunctionName("EmailNotification")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
        {
```

Comment: Why would you want to call another Azure Function? Just put your logic in another class and consume that from the first function.

Comment: actually email notification function will get called from all other functions so making that as a separate function instead put code in every function

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that comment. But I think what you said reinforces my first comment - you should inject an email service into your first function, not call another function.

Comment: second function will be a common code which will send an email so all 10+ functions will call second function instead duplicate the code in same functions.

Comment: I'm not telling you to duplicate code, I'm telling you to put the email code in a class of its own and use that same class in all functions where you need to send email.

Comment: @Neo you want to test two functions locally, in general and the email stuff only was an example?

Comment: @FalcoAlexander yes it is

Comment: @DavidG sorry i think i misunderstand could you please post a sample answer here ?

Comment: I'm not sure how I can explain it any simpler. Make a class called `EmailService` and put all email code in there. Use in an instance of that class in your function whenever you need it. That's just basic OOP programming.

Comment: I have 10+ other azure functions in different solutions. which i want to use EmailService code.

Comment: I have created a separate azure function for EmailService and hosted separately and want to call that from all other functions

Comment: What @DavidG means is just basically extract the body of your EmailService function and put it into its own class so it can be reused by your 10+ other functions. Another way to put it: In a WinForms app with 10 buttons and 1 'email' button, you wouldn't call the 'email' button's clicked handler directly but instead you would have extracted your email logic in a separate class and use it in your 10 buttons if they also need that functionality.
If your main problem is that you have separate function apps, then just use a shared project with your email class which gets referenced by all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume you have two function projects A, and B.

Let project A keep running on `localhost:7071/api/....` (The default port)

Change the project B to run on `localhost:8888/api/...` then add the command line switch `--nodeDebugPort 5859` to your launching of func host to set the port for one of the sessions.

If you are launching from within Visual Studio you need to go to `Project -> Properties -> Debug` then under Application arguments you need to pass in a value that looks similar to `host start --pause-on-error --nodeDebugPort 5859` **(again, for one project)**.